# C++11: template deduction and const types

Tags: c++11

Trying to use perfect forwarding, I hit a problem with template deduction.

The following compiles

```
template<typename T>
void forwarder(T&& x)
{
}

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    forwarder(x);
    return 0;
}
```

while it does not if I add `const` to the signature of the templated function.

```
template<typename T>
void forwarder(const T&& x)  // adding const here
{
}

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    forwarder(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Error message from `g++`

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:11:16: error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘const int&&’
test.cc:4:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void forwarder(const T&&) [with T = int]’
```

I can get it to work by specifiying `int&` as template parameter: `forwarder<int&>(x)`

I think adding a `const` even in templates might be useful, but my head hurts after some serious unsuccessful trying.

Can someone with a solid understanding of template deduction tell me what's going on here and whether using const with template deduction is possible and practical?

Comment: just curious, why are you making an rvalue (move) reference if it's a const? The point of a move reference is usually to alter the original object to a point where it's not usable anymore

Comment: There's not much to understand here: There's a special rule for `T&&` that doesn't apply to `T const&&` :) In Standardese, that is [temp.deduct.call]/3 "If `P` is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to `A`” is used in
place of `A` for type deduction."

Comment: The point of a move reference is usually to alter the original object to a point where it's not usable anymore

Comment: @Julius: That's a point I had not considered ;-)

Comment: @Julius: But my original motivation was perfect forwarding. `&&` on a template parameter type is not the same as on a fixed type.

Answer (score 0):

You are best off using type traits and tag dispatch to select a particular overload:

```
template<typename T>
void forwarder_impl(T&& x, std::true_type, std::true_type)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue reference to const\n";
}
template<typename T>
void forwarder_impl(T&& x, std::true_type, std::false_type)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue reference to non-const\n";
}
template<typename T>
void forwarder_impl(T&& x, std::false_type, std::true_type)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue reference to const\n";
}
template<typename T>
void forwarder_impl(T&& x, std::false_type, std::false_type)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue reference to non-const\n";
}

template<typename T>
void forwarder(T&& x)
{
    forwarder_impl(
        std::forward<T>(x),
        typename std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(x)>::type(),
        typename std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(x)>::type>::type()
    );
}

int main()
{
    const int x = 42;
    int y = 42;
    forwarder(std::move(x));
    forwarder(std::move(y));
    forwarder(x);
    forwarder(y);
}
```

Output:

```
rvalue reference to const
rvalue reference to non-const
lvalue reference to const
lvalue reference to non-const
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/vHZ7oC

Why you would ever want to do that remains a mystery.

---

If you wanted to restrict your `forwarder` to only accept references to const, you could use SFINAE to do that while preserving the universality of `T&&`:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value
>::type
forwarder(T&& x)
{
    auto value_cat = std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(x)>::value ? "r" : "l";
    std::cout << value_cat << "value reference to const\n";
}

int main()
{
    const int x = 42;
    forwarder(std::move(x));
    forwarder(x);
    //int y = 42;
    //forwarder(std::move(y));  //compile-time error
    //forwarder(y);             //compile-time error
}
```

Output:

```
rvalue reference to const
lvalue reference to const
```

http://ideone.com/t5UoZE
http://ideone.com/jc2Ek2

Once again, the motivation for such a thing is beyond me.

---

Resources: https://www.google.com/search?q=scott+meyers+universal+references